# Is the [apathy] tag of any use? Should we get rid of it?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

As [pointed out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47695631#47695631) in chat, seems that we have an [apathy](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apathy) tag, which is in the current state:

- Only 2 questions with it
- Those questions are 3+ years ago
- No wiki and no excerpt
- Contributes few to the post and finding a solution to it, perhaps even added/created in a rant moment
- Other tags the posts have are more suited and describe them better.

Not to mention that "apathy" is quite broad and could be considered a [Meta Tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) (which should go fo good).

**Should we remove, a.k.a., Burninate this tag?**

<sub>(I can do it if you want, but we should hear the Community consensus on this one before proceeding)</sub>

Comment: Yes, no, I don't care

Comment: We have far too many tags to be useful. Dump it.

Comment: @RichardU - I see what you did there... and I liked it!

Comment: Send it to trogdor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took that from the currently +7/-1 votes and comments on the post that the Consensus is to burninate this tag. Thus, I proceeded to remove it. It is now reduced to ashes...

[image: trogdor]

Comment: ALL HAIL TROGDOR